# jQuery Fullcalendar change class for single element of event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, addclass

I'm trying to change the class for only a *portion* of a single event using jQuery FullCalendar.

In particular, the div .fc-event-time. I could use:

```
$('.fc-event-time').addClass('event-updated');
```

...but then it changes the class for all the events on the schedule. I tried using "event." as well as "$(this).", but neither worked.

Again, I'm not trying to change the class of the entire event as shown here (className):
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

I am just trying to change the class for only the time portion after a successful ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "schedule.php",
        data: 'update=' + id + '&start=' + newStart + '&end=' + newEnd, 
        success: function(data){ 
        // change .fc-event-time class of THIS event
        }

    });
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Is it the DOM-element you want to add a class to? I don't think you can reach that without searching through all elements that are of type .fc-event-time and check the html (i.e. match a string to the time specified in the html). However this would give you all events that start and end the same time. What is it you want to achieve by changing class? Perhaps there's something else you can do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' , this.id).addClass('fc-event-udpated')
```

should do what you want, assuming you have a *this* event object that is pointing to the current event you want to change.

Comment: No, I can change the class of the entire event easily using the className property. I need to change the class of a single div that is part of the entire element.

Comment: this looked very promising... but i get "addClass is not a function" error. any ideas?? thanks!

Comment: If it has been the case, `clientEvents` does not return jquery objects anymore in the current version (1.6.4).

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this using `jQuery find()`:

```
$(this).find('.fc-event-time').addClass('newclass');
```

This enables you to change the class or otherwise modify a single *element* within a single event.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

NOTE: I have only been able to get this to work with the following callbacks:

```
dayClick (callback)
eventClick (callback)
eventMouseover (callback)
eventMouseout (callback)
```

It seems like `$(this)` does not work with any of the other callbacks, and I can't figure out any other way to select THIS element.

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it